# clojure function to return files in directory

Tags: clojure

I am trying to make a clojure function that returns the files in a directory that are changed today.
It's part of functionality => give me all files changed today, loop through the files  and look for a specific value. List both the file and the line with the value.

I got the parsing part + listing lines/files working as well as the 'changed files', however I struggle to merge the two.

The function I designed so far to find the changed files is:

```
(defn returnfilelist
"returns all the files changed today in a directory"
[d]
(def dir (io/file d))
  (def files (for [file (file-seq dir) :when (= (datetostr (Date.(.lastModified file))) (datetostr (new Date))) ](str file  )))
(doseq [f files] (println f) )) ;; <==== this indeed shows the files changed today...
```

I created the datetostr function to do the actual compare of the dates:

```
(defn datetostr [date]
 (str (.format (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyyMMdd")(.getTime date))))
```

This function indeed lists all the files changed today.
What I would like to do now is pass the 'files' into a function like:

```
(defn readdir [d]
 (ff/returnfilelist d)) ;; more to add...
```

for further processing.

I'd appreciate some help on this one, I'm probably overseeing something simple yet it kept me bugging for a couple of hours now. I've been searching in the clojure documentation and on the internet, yet I didn't figure out the right search expression to get the answer.

Direction is sufficient, I like to learn and I'm fairly new to programming clojure.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1. returnfilelist uses `def` inside of a function.  `def` defines and binds symbols in the package's global namespace, which is almost never what you want to do. Use `let` instead for function-local symbol binding.
2. returnfilelist never actually returns what it has calculated.  The last statement in the function, involving the doseq, actually returns nil.  You probably want to return files instead.

Here is returnfilelist with the appropriate changes (I've kept it as close to your original implementation as possible to illustrate the key changes to get your code working: the other answers using `filter` are more idiomatic, and should be preferred):

```
(defn returnfilelist
  "returns all the files changed today in a directory"
  [d]
  (let [dir (io/file d)
        files (for [file (file-seq dir) 
                    :when (= (datetostr (Date.(.lastModified file))) 
                             (datetostr (new Date)))]
                (str file))]
    (doseq [f files] (println f)) ;; leaving this in for debugging
    files)) ;; <--- the actual return value
```

...and readdir becomes:

```
(defn readdir [d]
  (let [todays-files (ff/returnfilelist d)] 
  ;; more to add...
))
```

Comment: Thanks YosemiteMark for your reply. I didn't know how to return the value and use it. Since all you three made the same comment about let, filter and idiom I need to look more into that. I will be looking into understanding your code first so I can understand what went wrong in my code, after that I will look at the other two to learn more about the clojure language structure.

Answer (score 0):

To have a value returned from a function it has to be produced by the last statement executed within. In your case, you're not returning anything, but defining new values in the global scope (which is bad practice in itself); you should use `let` for local values:

```
(defn files-modified-today
  [path]
  (let [dir (io/file dir)]
    (filter modified-today? (file-seq dir))))
```

(Implement `modified-today?` to your liking, e.g. like you did in your question using `datetostr`.)

Since the `for` form is the last statement executed in the function its result will be used as the function's return value and can be used from elsewhere:

```
(defn read-dir
  [path]
  (for [f (files-modified-today path)]
    (let [result (parse-file f)]
      [f result]))))
```

This will return a seq of pairs, containing the matched file as first element and the result of `parse-file` (whatever that may be) as the second one.

I hope I didn't miss your question completely.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague.  Also, it seems like the code you are writing is far from idiomatic.  I've rewritten some of your functions below to introduce you to some common clojure idioms.

```
(import 'java.util.Date)

(defn date->str [date]
  (-> (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyyMMdd")              ;thread-first macro
      (.format (.getTime date))
      str))

(defn todays-files [dir]
  "returns all the files changed today in a directory"
  (let [today (new Date)]                                   ;let bindings
    (->> (file-seq (clojure.java.io/file dir))              ;thread-last macro.
         (filter #(= (date->str (Date. (.lastModified %))) (date->str today)))
         (map str))))
```

The threading macros (thread-first and thread-last) are used to create pipelines where a single data transformation is performed, then passed to the next step.

let bindings should be used instead of defs inside functions.

function names should have dashes where spaces normally are.  It is also common to use -> for conversion functions.  For example date-to-str becomes date->str.

Answer (score 0):

A macro to take care of list the files in directory - recursively or just in the parent directory. It can also search files with specific ending extension.

```
;; lists all the files recursively inside the directory passed as d like "."
(defmacro my-rec-list
  "generate the recursive list" {:added "1.0"}
  [d str rec]
  `(->> ~d
       clojure.java.io/file
       ~(if (= rec "rec")
          `file-seq
          `(.listFiles)) 
       ~(cond 
          (= str "file")  `(filter #(.isFile %))
          (= str "dir")   `(filter #(.isDirectory %))
          :always         `(filter #(.matches (.getPathMatcher 
                          (java.nio.file.FileSystems/getDefault)
                          ~str) (.getFileName (.toPath %)))))
       (mapv #(.getAbsolutePath %))))


(defn my-rec-ls-file 
  "generate the recursive list for only files in a directory"
  [d ] 
  (my-rec-list d "file" "rec"))
(defn my-rec-ls-dir 
  "generate the recursive list for only directory"
  [d ] 
  (my-rec-list d "dir" "rec"))
(defn my-rec-ls-jpg 
  "generate the recursive list for files and directory"
  [d ] 
  (my-rec-list d "glob:*.jpg" "rec"))
(defn my-ls-file 
  "generate the recursive list for only files in a directory"
  [d ] 
  (my-rec-list d "file" "norec"))
(defn my-ls-dir 
  "generate the recursive list for only directory"
  [d ] 
  (my-rec-list d "dir" "norec"))
(defn my-ls-jpg 
  "generate the recursive list for files and directory"
  [d ] 
  (my-rec-list d "glob:*.jpg" "norec"))
```

It leads to different function which can be called with directory to get the list of files, directory or matching extension file - recursively or non-recursively. Example is -

```
(def directory (clojure.java.io/file "/Path/to/Directory"))
(my-rec-ls-jpg directory) ;; find all jpg file recessively in directory
(my-ls-jpg directory) ;; find jpg file in current directory
```